# C Modulo not working

Tags: c, modulo

Whenever I try to modulo by 0xE2089EA5 in the code `(v * v) % 0xE2089EA5` the modulo is simply ignored. `v` is an unsigned long. I have checked with a calculator, and all of the numbers I am passing it is greater than the modulo and the calculator is returning a remainer that is not the least 32 bits.

Are there any restrictions on C's modulo operator that I am not aware of?

Comment: Try changing `0xE2089EA5` to `0xE2089EA5UL`.

Comment: You should show us an MCVE ([MCVE]).  It needn't be very complex.  Just show us how you set `v` and how you capture and print the results, and what you get and what you expect as the result.  Are you compiling with 32-bit or 64-bit `unsigned long`?

Comment: @PaulR: if `v` is `unsigned long`, making the constant explicitly `unsogned long` too shouln't make any difference.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: you're probably right, but I thought it was worth a try.

Comment: If `v` is `unsigned long`, the result of `v*v` is also `unsigned long`.  If that overflows, it will be truncated (modulo arithmetic) so it fits in an `unsigned long`.   Before your `%0xE2089EA5`.

Comment: the size of `long` depends on platform. It's not always 64 bits

Comment: I think overflow is probably suspect here. I probably need to check the size of long.